# languages required to do an AI project?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Is it necessary to learn programming languages like Lisp, Perl, Ruby,etc (whatever required ) to do a project in AI?
I know C,C++,Java well, is that sufficient to go on with my AI project?

Comment: Usually when you ask this question, its about whatever your most productive and proficient in.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on type of your project. Read following posts.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82036/what-is-a-good-programming-language-for-ai/83871#83871
- [Good Programming Languages for AI](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp00/cse151/q1/crocha.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can write in any language.  A lot of AI work has been done in Lisp, but you aren't required to use it to implement your project.  A solid understanding of the algorithms is the key.

You might find that algorithms that depend heavily on recursion are more difficult in languages like Java that don't support tail recursion *optimization*.

Comment: Every language "supports" tail recursion. Same language implementations are simply better at optimizing them than others. Some language (e.g. Scheme) even specify that a conforming implementation of the language has to apply TCO --- tail call optimization. Surprisingly for many, GCC applies TCO to C.

Answer (score 1):

You can do AI programming in Java. You probably could do it in any language as its just the algorithms that are important.

See [here for AI code in Java and other languages.](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no such a thing as a "good programming language for AI". Programming languages are tools, and it really depends what your AI project is about: just choose the most appropriate one for it. For example, if you're going to work with Semantic Web and ontologies, then Java is probably a good choice, because there are a lot of good Java libraries and tools in that area. Conversely, I know that many people working on machine learning use R, because it is a powerful statistical computing environment. Alternatively, if your AI project is about logic programming or computational linguistic, then you should probably have a look at Prolog.

In summary, it really depends on what is your AI project. Tell us more about it, and you'll probably get more precise answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your doing - choose the best tool for the job.

If you're doing classic AI (Natural Language Processing, Expert Systems, etc) then languages like Lisp and Prolog are a good fit (the language facilitates easy development), however if you're doing Fuzzy Logic, Neural Networks etc then Java/C++ would be a better choice.

Years ago as an undergrad I wrote some NLP and Expert Systems in Prolog and then repeated the exercise in C++, the Prolog versions were around a third of the size and took about half the time to develop.  I wrote a few Fuzzy Logic and Neural Nets in C++, but never fancied rewriting them in Prolog (I sure that would have been quite painful)  =)

A nice, feature rich Java framework for Neural Nets is [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog)